# Borrar datos en sql

Tags: sql-server

Como puedo borrar datos de una tabla.

Por ejemplo... De tal id a otro, del id 1 al 10. sin tener que poner un delete from tabla where id = 1 varias veces.

Comment: where id >= 1 and id <= 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
Delete t
From tabla t
Where id between 1 and 10
```